# Change how items are displayed WPF list box

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemspaneltemplate

I have a WPF window which displays a `ListBox`. I've changed the `ListBox`'s item template so that the list box displays rectangular items which can be selected.

Now I'd like to modify the `ListBox`'s `ItemsPanelTemplate` so that the items are displayed in a grid instead of either a vertical or horizontal list. Specifically I'd like the first item to go in the top right corner of the `ListBox` and then second item below it and third under that until the height of the next item would make the column of items taller than the height of the `ListBox` itself. At that point it should start a second column directly to the right of the first item added. If the total width of all of the columns combined was greater than width of the `ListBox` then a horizontal scroll bar should appear.

Is there a way to get that effect just by modifying the `ItemsPanelTemplate` or do I need to extend the `ListBox` class itself? In either case, how would I got about it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I suspect you can get the desired effect by swapping out the default panel used by the `ListBox` to a `WrapPanel`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That basically solves it, but the code above 'as is' still just creates a long vertical list.The trick to get it to create a grid as I described above is to add this attribute to the ListBox tag:

ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"