# How can a WPF ListBox, with a custom ItemsPanel template, resize itself based on the size of its items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, autosize, itemspaneltemplate

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545519/change-how-items-are-displayed-wpf-list-box), which was answered.

Using the code:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

You can create a list where the items populate the `ListBox` in columns from left to right and the last item in a particular column is never cutoff (meaning if the item was to tall to fit, it is moved to the top of the next column). How could I now dynamically adjust the `Width` of the `ListBox` to 'fit' it's items and get that same behavior horizontally. So suppose the following:

If, at a given `Height`, there only needed to be one `Column` to fit all of the items the `Width` of the `ListBox` should be the size of the `Width` of the items.

Or, at a given `Height` there needs to be four `Column`s, it would need to be size to four times the `Width` of the items.

Finally, say at a given `Height` there needs to be more `Column`s than the maximum allowed `Width` of the `ListBox`, it would need to calculate how wide it should be so that the items in the `Column`s that would not be able to fit were not truncated but just not shown until the user scrolled to the right.

Thanks for your help!!

**EDIT:**

I think a simpler way to phrase the above is that I'm looking for a way to avoid 'clipping' items in the list. I'd like to create a list that displays items in grid but where you wouldn't have to scroll because some items were partially covered and would require you to scroll to the right or left to see the remainder of that item (though the list could only be so wide or tall and if there were enough items you'd still need to scroll to see all of them, just any items you saw should be fully displayed).  Also I only care about the initial drawing of the list. It doesn't have to 'snap' items to always fit but it should be able to be scrolled so that it fills the available space completely with the items it does display.

It seemed to me the key do doing this is to figure out the size of a list item at runtime and the size of the content container in the listbox and then you could adjust it to completely fit so many items at once before the list is initially drawn?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post an example of somewhere maybe on the web with the behavior you want... it's still not clear what your reqs are.

Comment: Say I had a list like the one in this example: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=29384, how could I alter that example so that when it first displayed the list only items that were fully visible could be seen? By fully visible I mean part of one of those boxes should not be covered by end of the container in such a way that you'd have to scroll to see all of that item.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty complicated question. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish here... *does the number of columns you see need to increase or decrease as the height increases*?  I would hope decrease, but the way you worded your question it seems you want the opposite and I'm trying to understand this.

I think a basic understanding of WPF's layout system is really useful when trying to understand these questions.  Another thing that is useful is that the *size of something is largely determined by its layout container*, rather than the thing itself.

In your question, you ask how to get your ListBox to dynamically size based on the contents.  A *ListBox is not a layout control*, but something like a WrapPanel is.  The function of a WrapPanel is to say at the same width, even if the contents of the Panel increases in size.  This is not the same for other controls, like a Grid for example.

Here's a couple of good links about the layout system in WPF.  Hopefully this helps.  Come back with some clarification of your question and see if we can't get you some more help if you need it.

http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help (+1), those sites look like they will be very useful! I'm going to edit the question based on your feed back and see if I can make it clearer.